# why I can't do this method without the keyword "static"?

Tags: java, exception

Why the method "div" doesn't work without static.? when just remove the static keyword it gives me the Error i.e .."\Playground:13: error: non-static method div(int, int) cannot be referenced from a static context
        System.out.println(div(42, 0));"

```
public class Program {

    static int div(int a, int b) throws ArithmeticException {
        if(b == 0) {
            throw new ArithmeticException("Division by Zero");
        } else {
            return a / b;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(div(42, 2));
    }

}
```

Comment: Read up about `static` in java and then I believe you can *answer* the question yourself.

Comment: If the method `div` is not static how will `main` know which instance's `div` method to call?

Answer (score 0):

When you remove `static`, that makes `div` an *instance* method. So you must then change

```
System.out.println(div(42, 2));
```

to invoke `div` through an ***instance***. For example,

```
System.out.println(new Program().div(42, 2));
```